# Application crashes in emulator when loading native shared library, but works fine on a physical device

Tags: android, android-ndk

The header pretty much explains the issue. I'm getting "Unsatisfied link error" on emulator. What could be the cause and what are the possible solutions?

Some time ago, when we started developing the app, it did work fine on emulator, and one day just stopped. It happened on at least two independent machines.

Ideas, anyone?..

**Update**: created a new emulator - same thing.

Comment: don't you get any exceptions on the logcat? you should start following the logcat messages as soon as you start the launch of the app. it should display there some warnings/errors if it can load the native shared library..

Comment: @OvidiuLatcu: sorry, should have written the exception mesaage. Updated the question.

Comment: @OvidiuLatcu: It's in the problem description, so it doesn't stand out. I'm getting "Unsatisfied link error" on emulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved! it appears, Android QUEMU emulator only supports ARM5 (`APP_ABI:=armeabi`), and my library was compiled with `armeabi-v7a`.

Update: the problem no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the following :

1. Using `adb shell` go in to the `sys/lib/` folder and check if your library was copied there
2. Did you change the package of your class or did some refactoring? If you did and didn't updated the `.cpp` file this is causing the `unsatisfied link error`.
3. You can also try to manually load your library using `System.loadLibrary("myLib");`
4. You could also try to create a new emulator, maybe it got messed some how. Happens a lot.

Comment: Of course, I am using `System.loadLibrary` - and getting this error on emulator, but not on real device. The library is integrated into APK fine. As for your 4th suggestion - thanks, will try, but I doubt it is the case since two dev PCs got this issue simultaneously, starting at the same moment.

Comment: Tried recreating emulator - no luck.